# Assets\movebullet.cs(19,26): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movebullet : MonoBehaviour
{


void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.Translate(0,0.05f,0);
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.GameObject.CompareTag("willdie")){
    
       
        Destroy(this GameObject);
        Destroy(other.GameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Im trying to make a space invaders game and that is the bullet code/
can you pls help me with the error?
thanks

Comment: _this.GameObject_ missing the point

Comment: In these cases, please add a comment in your code, pointing to the line with the error - I don't want to count to line 19, knowing that the linecount here may be different from your own file (did you copy every line?)

Comment: Either way note that the property is called lower case [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @steve in comment, you're lacking a point in this line:

```
Destroy(this GameObject);
```

like this:

```
Destroy(this.GameObject);
```

I would add also that to reference the GameObject that the script is attached to, it's written with non capital g, like this:

```
Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

Also you don't have to add "this.", like this:

```
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Also, when you destroy the GameObject attached to the script, the script stops running, so you have to change the order of these 2 lines:

```
Destroy(gameObject);
Destroy(other.gameObject);
```

To This:

```
Destroy(other.gameObject);
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Your script would end up looking like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movebullet : MonoBehaviour{

    void FixedUpdate(){
        transform.Translate(0,0.05f,0);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("willdie")){
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `when you destroy the GameObject attached to the script, the script stops running, so you have to change the order of these 2 lines` .. no that's not true. This is `c#` after all and a method doesn't simply stop in the middle. Additionally the actual destruction of the object is delayed until somewhere at the end of the frame and it might even take longer until GC cleans it up finally

Comment: Besides that: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) ;)